# Q: find longest string using for loop (Bash)

Tags: bash, for-loop, unix

Im learning bash, and I have an assignment where I need to iterate through a list of strings in bash using a for loop, and return the longest string.

This is what I've written:

```
max=-1
word=""
list=`cat random-text.txt | tr -s [:space:] " " | sed -r 's/([.* ])/\1\n/g' | grep -E "^a.*" | sed -r 's/(.*)[[:space:]]/\1/' | tr -s [:space:] " "`
                    for i in $list; do
                            int=`$i | wc -c`
                            if [ $int > $max ]; then
                                    max=$int
                                    word=$i
                            fi
                    done
                    echo The longest word in $infile that starts with $char is $i
```

that's probably a bit messy, but I'm having trouble using the for loop (I need the echo function at the end to return the longest string I have found iterating through the array.

** that's a part of a longer script I've written, I

Thanks in advance, much appreciated!

Comment: An excerpt from your input file and the expected output for that would be more helpful.

Comment: hi. my input is a random short story which contains only letters and punctuation marks.  an expected output is : The longest word in random-text.txt that starts with h is hello.

Comment: for some reason, while I run this script I get an error which says: "Command 'an' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install an" - and at that point I can only terminate the script using Ctrl+C

Comment: And is it guaranteed that `char` is always an alphanumeric character or can it be a punctuation mark too (which wouldn't make any sense at all, but still)?

Answer (score 1):

> for some reason, while I run this script I get an error which says: "Command 'an' not found

That's because you erroneously used `$i |` to feed the content of variable `i` to `wc`; correct is `<<<$i` instead (with Bash). But better use just `int=${#i}`.

Then in `$int > $max` the `>` is interpreted as an output redirection; the correct arithmetic comparison operator is `-gt`.

Finally you don't `echo` the *longest word* found, but rather the last processed one; change `$i` to `$word` there.

Comment: It seems to me that `int=\`wc -c<<<$i\`` will count a LF char ? Should not it be then `int=\`printf "$i"|wc -c\`` to keep it strictly to the variable content ?

Comment: You are quite right in that an additional LF is counted, but since the count is needed only for finding the maximum, this offset doesn't matter for the result.

Comment: @Zilog80 - Anyway, I added a precise and also better way. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: You're welcome. Nice catch, and POSIX shell compliant too ^^ (I should have thought it)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer!! I finally managed to figure it out.